# How to read the content of a file in a post-receive hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm building a hook for the post-receive and I need to read the content of a file (VERSION). This file can change along with the commit (new version) so I can't read an existing repo.

I tried this method :

```
git cat-file blob $(git ls-files -s VERSION | awk '{print $2}')
```

But in the hook folder, it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: `git show $commit:$file` ?

Comment: perfect! Add it as an answer, I will validate it, and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use

```
git show $commit:$file
```